# Can we have negative modulo in modular arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why can't we have modulo to a negative number? I have never seen this.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying yourself? What did it result in?

Answer (score 3):

We can, but you'll notice by looking at the definition that $a\equiv b\pmod {(-n)}\iff a\equiv b\pmod n$, so it's a bit silly.